# JS replace all the string before another specified character

Tags: javascript, replace

I have the string

```
var str = "A > B > C > D > E";
```

expected output:

```
E
```

Means i want to remove/replace all the string upto last `>` symbol, or before `>` symbol from last.

Javascript `replace` will do the trick, but i don't know how to write the pattern for this.

or can we do this by `split` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex :

```
var str = "A > B > C > D > E";
var re = str.replace(/.*> /,"");

# print "E"
```

Comment: ah it's worked, i was trying this from last 1 hour. thank u so  much.

Answer (score 2):

Goran's solution is correct and beautiful (because of the regex). However, here's an alternative using String's `.split` method:

```
var str = "A > B > C > D > E";
var letters = str.split(' > '); 
var output = letters[letters.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even simpler than using `split` or `replace`. Locate the last separator, and take the part of the string after that:

```
str = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(' > ') + 3);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ahgB2/

Comment: nice solution. new approach.